# If a question is badly asked, does answering it mean I am "encouraging" the one who asked to make crap posts?

Tags: discussion, answers, bad-questions

So if a question is crap, does this mean that I shouldn't answer the question because I'll be "encouraging" the asker? I mean, if *I* understood the question, it doesn't mean that *no one* will understand it. And to make things better, I add some advise at the end saying that his post is badly asked.

Comment: If you understand it then answer it. If it's actually cr@p and you're **guessing** at the meaning to provide an answer...I'd say no, you shouldn't answer.

Comment: If it's badly asked, how do you know you're actually answering it? And how will anyone else with the same issue find it and therefore your answer? If it's badly asked, your time is better spent commenting to encourage the OP to clarify and voting to close as unclear to stop other people making that mistake.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know I'm answering it because I found there's only one way for his question to make sense.

Comment: There's a distinct risk you're overestimating the OP there...

Comment: Note that the specific question is [not even clearly a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37773042), let alone a clearly *answerable* one.

Comment: Oh *wow* that's bad. Yeah, you shouldn't have answered that.

Comment: @PaulRoub Don't bring up the question I didn't mention. And plus, he was asking for clarification on the new interface. He clearly hasn't updated android studio, because in both pics he has AS 2.1.1, he was creating a new project incorrectly.

Comment: To restate, I wasn't guessing, if you look at an angle, there's only one way for his question to make sense. So instead of being unhelpful, I'm trying to be helpful in best ways.

Comment: *"Don't bring up the question I didn't mention."* I respectfully decline the order.

Comment: No, you aren't being helpful (although I'm sure you're trying). Spend your time on people who bothered to write decent questions, because they're the ones that benefit people other than the OP.

Comment: Try to remember that, at the end of the day, the OPs are inconsequential. We are building a long lasting repository of knowledge. A question like that one is not helpful to anyone but the OP. In the grand scheme of how stack helps, this is way off the mark.

Comment: Well then again, I probably shouldn't have answered. But again, I'm  sure I answered his question, let's see what the OPs do.

Comment: @Abappletic again, getting HIM out of his issue isn't really Stack's goal. We get closer to Stack's goal everytime a great question gets a +1 view and helps some random coder. Seriously, what is the chance THAT question ever pops up in a search engine?